# local variable 'CompletelyUniqueName' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables

I've looked through as many answers on this subject as I could find and all suggested that it's a global - local conflict. I can't see how this would apply in my case but please do explain. Here's the error :

"local variable 'CompletelyUniqueName' referenced before assignment"

and here is the code, a function I call from another script :

```
def geopixsum(filename):
    # register all of the GDAL drivers
    gdal.AllRegister()
    # Check file type (in this case Geotiff)
    if filename.endswith('.tif'):
        # open the image
        try:
            inDs = gdal.Open(filename)
        except:
          print 'Could not open ',file,'\n'
        # get image size
        rows = inDs.RasterYSize
        cols = inDs.RasterXSize
        # read band 1 into data
        band1 = inDs.GetRasterBand(1)
        data = band1.ReadAsArray(0,0,cols,rows)
        # get nodata value
        nandat = band1.GetNoDataValue()
        sumvals = data[np.where(np.logical_not(data == nandat))]
        CompletelyUniqueName = sumvals.sum()
        print 'sum = ',CompletelyUniqueName
    inDs = None
    return CompletelyUniqueName
```

This code worked when not a function but rather just a script on its own. Again, I know this would make it it seem like a global - local issue but given the name I've assigned the variable I think I've gone to great enough lengths to avoid a conflict.

Comment: `if filename.endswith('.tif'):` if this condition fails then `return CompletelyUniqueName` is going to raise that error.

Comment: True, I'll address that, but it's been receiving a tif. Get back on that ASAP

Comment: Yup, that was it. The script calling the function chopped the .tif off before passing the file name to the function. Still, as a catchall I am now assigning an error message to the variable before the if loop runs. I got so locked in to not needing to initiate variables in Python I forgot that there may be other causes of failure: stupidity on my part. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should either define default value for `CompletelyUniqueName` (for case if `filename.endswith('.tif') == False`)

```
def geopixsum(filename):
    CompletelyUniqueName = 0 
    if filename.endswith('.tif'):
        ...
        CompletelyUniqueName = sumvals.sum()
    return CompletelyUniqueName
```

Or return inside `if` statement

```
def geopixsum(filename):
    if filename.endswith('.tif'):
        ...
        CompletelyUniqueName = sumvals.sum()
        return CompletelyUniqueName
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix:

```
def geopixsum(filename):
    CompletelyUniqueName = 0    # or None, or anything you want to return 
                                # if the file is not a tif
    # register all of the GDAL drivers
    gdal.AllRegister()
    # Check file type (in this case Geotiff)
    if filename.endswith('.tif'):
        # open the image
        try:
            inDs = gdal.Open(filename)
        except:
          print 'Could not open ',file,'\n'
        # get image size
        rows = inDs.RasterYSize
        cols = inDs.RasterXSize
        # read band 1 into data
        band1 = inDs.GetRasterBand(1)
        data = band1.ReadAsArray(0,0,cols,rows)
        # get nodata value
        nandat = band1.GetNoDataValue()
        sumvals = data[np.where(np.logical_not(data == nandat))]
        CompletelyUniqueName = sumvals.sum()
        print 'sum = ',CompletelyUniqueName
    inDs = None
    return CompletelyUniqueName
```